# regular expression to enter at least two alphanumeric words

Tags: regex

how can i modify my regular expression to enter at least two words in the text box.
Here is my regular expression. lets say user can **not** **enter** only "**miranda**", she has to **enter** "**miranda klose**".

```
[Required]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 10, 
        ErrorMessage = "Name must have minimum 10 and maximum 50 characters.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?![\W_]+$)(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 .&',_-]+$", 
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid Name ")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: FWIW, "miranda" is already an error because it does not meet your minimum length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to,

```
@"^(?![\W_]+$)(?!\d+$)[\w .&',-]+(?:\s[\w .&',-]+)+$"
```

`+` repeats the previous token one or more times. So by putting `+` after the capturing or non-capturing would make the whole group to repeat one or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sY4uC9/4)

```
@"^(?![\W_]+$|\s)(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 .&',_-]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9 .&',_-]+)+$"
```

This won't match the names which has spaces at the start.

Comment: The regex may be more readable with the help of `\w` character class.

Comment: sorry, directly copied the op's regex.

Comment: it is working fine but its allowing whitespace before the name, how can i avoid that.please help.